# Transaction expired

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter, phantom-wallet

[image: phantom app]

Hello everyone. When I press the send transaction button while on the Phantom devnet network, I can send it to Solana. I get this error when I switch to mainnet and try to send transaction. Is it because I'm in localhost?
In the application, I did not write the code for the select any network part. How can I switch to the mainnet?

Answer (score 1):

without the code its a bit hard to tell, but if you use wallet adapter it maybe smth like this:

```
    <ConnectionProvider endpoint={endpoint}>
```

Where the endpoint is the cluster url.

Could also be that you create a connection manually somewhere, then you would need to search for connection:

```
export const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"), {
  commitment: "confirmed",
})
```

Hope this gives you a hint what to search for in your project.
Here is an example game in case you need a reference:
https://github.com/solana-developers/solana-game-starter-kits/tree/main/tiny-adventure

Answer (score 0):

In phantom wallet find settings then find developer setting, and you can change network in phantom wallet. The network in phantom wallet and The network in  should be the same

Comment: yes i know that but i want to transfer on mainnet. I can't figure out what I need to change to mainnet in my application.